# To What does the Scout Mastery Apply?

Tags: league-of-legends

The wikia says that the Scout Mastery only applies to wards. however, I heard elsewhere that it works for traps (i.e. Caitlyn's Traps). Is this true? Does it also work for other revealing spells (Ashe's Hawkeye, Kog's Ultimate, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, what you heard elsewhere is incorrect. The tool tip for the Scout Mastery reads as follows-

***Wards gain 25% increased vision range for the first 5 seconds after placing them.***

Riot is fairly straight forward when it comes to Runes and Mastery's and as such the tool tip would specifically say it affected champion abilities and summoner spells as well.

It is possible that for a time this was the case, but it would have been fixed once it was brought to RIOT's attention.

[image]

Comment: just like the teemo invis recall im sure.

Comment: Except that Teemo's invisible recall has nothing to do with runes or mastery's. Same as the time when Anivia would be sent into egg form regardless of how long ago she was egged previous.

Comment: it was from masteries that used to allow him to recall during his invis...

Comment: Sorry, but without you providing me with some kind of proof that it was the mastery specifically that allowed Teemo to recall while invisible and not a bug after a patch, I'm going to have to call shenanigans.

Comment: [Proof](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xq-hALDpv_E)...never underestimate the scout's code.

Comment: So it was a glitch with the mastery specifically, ok, you win. That still doesn't change the fact that it was not working as intended and was fixed by RIOT to work correctly in a reasonable time.